# Json Format for a TimeSpan that can be bound using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

In a project I need to configure some third party library via the Micorosoft.Extensions.Configuration.

The library gives an options class and I used the configurationSection.Bind(optionsClassInstance) method to bind the values.

It works well except the nested TimeSpan value. 
I can't figure out what the json structure of a timespan is so it could be bound.

There are no errors. The values from the json are simply not bound.

So far I just used "timespan": { "Days": 0, "Hours": 1, "Minutes": 0 }

---

Thanks to the answer I tested successfully the given values with the given results:

1.02:03:04.567 = 1 day, 2 hours, 3 minutes, 4 seconds, 567 milliseconds

1.02:03:04 = 1 day, 2 hours, 3 minutes, 4 seconds, 0 milliseconds

02:03:04   = 0 days, 2 hours, 3 minutes, 4 seconds, 0 milliseconds

03:04      = 0 days, 3 hours, 4 minutes, 0 seconds, 0 milliseconds

04         = 4 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds, 0 milliseconds

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Timespan format in .net core is `D.HH:mm:nn` (so "1.02:03:04" is 1 day, 2 hours, 3 mins, 4 seconds).

javascript wont be able to read that (we use a custom JsonConverter for timespan objects for that reason), but .Net can.

```
{"timespan":"1.02:03:04"}
```

Comment: You can also specify milliseconds, e.g. `{"timespan":"1.02:03:04.200"}`